# Is there `find`'s `-exec` like option in `ack-grep`?

Tags: find, ack

I want to remove all texts that include string `foo`.

I can list all files by `ack-grep foo`, but I couldn't find a way to remove all files like `-exec rm {}` option like `find`.

How can I delete all files that contains particular string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `xargs`:

```
ack -l --print0 foo | xargs -r0 rm --
```

ack's `--print0` and xargs' `-0` cause ack and xargs to write and read using NUL as the delimiter, which guarantees proper filename handling. Without it, `xargs` will accept a far more wide range of characters as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use option -l with grep and ack which lists only filename:

```
grep -l --null foo ./* | xargs -r0 rm
```

or:

```
ack -l --print0 foo ./* | xargs -r0 rm --
```

Comment: This is dangerous, any filenames containing whitespace will be handled improperly, and could cause unexpected files to be removed.

Comment: There could be problems with `grep` and `rm` if a directory is included in the search directory